# How can I make a PyCharm server running locally available to iPhone on same network

Tags: ios, iphone, server, pycharm

I am developing a backend server for an app using PyCharm. This runs on my laptop as 127.0.0.1:8000

I need to access this server for testing from an iPhone. This is connected by wifi to my local network to which the laptop is also connected.

I have tried entering http://mycomputer.local:8000 in safari on the iPhone but I get the message "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped working. I am using the real name of my computer instead of 'mycomputer'.

I am running OS X Yosemite so Web Sharing is not available in System Preferences.

How can I give access to the 127.0.0.1:8000 server to my iPhone?

Comment: Look for ip your laptop has and connect to this ip. Your network cannot resolve dns lookup.

Comment: My laptop is on http://192.168.1.200 entering this, or http://192.168.1.200:8000 in a iPhone browser gives a can't connect to server message.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "backend server", what is the Python project written in? Django, Flask, Pyramid, something else?

Comment: The code is the server for an app and is written in Django

Comment: In that case, go into the Django settings and change the IP address. As mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) "Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled)."

Comment: Thanks for that that makes sense. I can't though see in the documentation what setting I need for the settings.py file. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, just found the settings in PyCharm and have changed the server address. Many thanks for this. I thought it was something straight forward but just couldn't figure out what :)

Comment: Unfortunately even though my server is now running on 192.168.1.200:8000 I still can't access it from my iPhone. I am guessing this is a network issue and I need to give the iPhone access to my local network computers?

Comment: Try eliminating the PyCharm/Python part. Get a static web server running on your laptop. See if you can reach it from iOS. Or even, turn on your SSH server, install an SSH client on iOS, and try login.

Comment: Also, make sure your laptop and iOS are on the same WiFi network. "192" addresses won't always span a router. Finally, if your laptop is OS X, you could try using the Bonjour name (e.g. "somehost.local") instead of IP address in the URL.

Comment: I have tried the bonjour name billsmacbookpro.local:8000 and that gives the same server not found error. My iPhone is on the same sub network at 192.168.1.151. I don't know how to get a static webserver running on my laptop other than trough PyCharm or MAMP. MAMP sets the server to local.

Comment: Can you ping laptop from other device? Can you connect to server on the laptop via 127.0.0.1? Are you sure the server runs on port 8000?